# InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No Persistent Entity information found for the class com.mongodb.BasicDBList

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb, rest

I am trying to insert an array of json objects into mongodb. I pass the array with a `POST` request, using `Spring`

My object

```
@Document(collection = "Users")
public class User {
  private String name;
  private String number;
//constructors, getters, setters
}
```

My spring controller

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

  @RequestMapping(value="/postUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public void postUser(@RequestBody BasicDBList users){
    ApplicationContext ctx =
      new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringMongoConfig.class);
    MongoOperations mongoOperation =
      (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");
    mongoOperation.insert(users);
  }
}
```

This is my json

```
[
    {
        "name" : "a",
        "number" : "1"
    },
    {
        "name" : "c",
        "number" : "3"      
    }
]
```

What I get in return is

```
{
    "timestamp": 1499161260902,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException",
    "message": "No Persistent Entity information found for the class com.mongodb.BasicDBList",
    "path": "/postUser"
}
```

There is no problem if I do

```
public void postUser(@RequestBody User users)
```

and insert a single user. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add `@RequestBody` before the parameter, `HttpMessageConvertor` will try to convert json string to the specified type - `BasicDBList`. The json string may not match `BasicDBList`, so the conversion failed. You can use this:

```
public void postUser(@RequestBody List<User> users)
```

Comment: Did not help. New error is `com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBList`

Comment: Correction. I had to also change `mongoOperation.insert(users)` to `insertAll(users)`. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Spring data cannot determine the collection name to save BasicDBList.

This is not related to HttpMessageConverter

You can check more here:
[Insert DBObject into MongoDB using Spring Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421491/insert-dbobject-into-mongodb-using-spring-data/20421907)

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No Persitent Entity information found for the class com.mongodb.BasicDBObject at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.determineCollectionName(MongoTemplate.java:1747)
```